# Problem in page access after logout

Tags: java

When the user logs out of the app and if user clicks on back button he will be able to view the recently visited page and do all the operations again,how to handle this in java?

Comment: how do you know that a user is logged and what action do you take in the logout?

Comment: on login i will make a new session using 
  session=request.getSession(true);
 and on logout is do invalidate ,so after logout on back it again comes to the main servlet and works as asual,what i am doing wrong?

Comment: In actuality, you are not doing anything to check whether the user is still logged in. If the user come back after log out, the container will create a brand new session for him, and he would be perfectly fine in accessing pages, which he doesn't suppose to without logging in.

Comment: Y i got it,but how to do that check ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable caching for your pages. You can do that by doing something like this:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

Read [here](http://www.jsptube.com/examples/jsp-no-cache.html) for more details.

Comment: I am doing this,but still after logout user is able to do all operations.

Comment: ya all the 3 headers are added
#
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
#
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
#
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); //prevent caching at the proxy server

Answer (score 1):

First thing first,

- Store the user info in the session upon log in
- Remove that info upon logout. You should also take a look at `SessionListener`, in the case of time based logouts
- Every request from the user must go through a filter which checks the information stored in the session at log in time, if found give a go, otherwise redirect to login page.

**Caveat:** Back button will still work with GET requests. For that consider kgiannakakis's suggestion.

Best of luck.